# Why is my grease pencil stroke suddenly un-interactable?

Tags: grease-pencil

I've been using the *Grease Pencil* strokes in *Edit Mode* to make some custom designs, but seemingly out of nowhere one of my objects became effectively invisible, uneditable, etc. The stroke is clearly still there (but it can only be seen in wireframe view), and trying to erase the strokes results in "Nothing to erase or all layers locked." Even though so far as I can tell, none of the layers are locked.

I'm not sure if this is a bug (I'm using the 3.4 alpha) or if I hit a setting of some sort and didn't realize it. Does anyone know what's going on? Because if this is just me missing a setting somewhere (I'm pretty unfamiliar with the grease pencil as a whole) I don't want to make a bug report.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoose signs are trace of an existing keyframe, that activates at frame 184, where they become visible and editable, even in solid or rendered view.

Comment: Thank you so, so much!